# Libre office calc hanging issue

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using Libre office 7.1.3.2 and it is hanging when I edit anything in the office calc.

Sometimes I tried to edit .ods file but it hangs after accessing the file for few minutes specifically editing data.

Comment: This is the all details about operating system-                                    
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.04"
VERSION_ID="21.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirsute
UBUNTU_CODENAME=hirsute

Comment: Use "edit" to add useful information that may help solving the problem to your question itself: use "edit". Comments may not be read or may disappear.